# How can I create a stream for DockerDotNet BuildImageFromDockerfile method?

Tags: c#, docker

I am trying to build a Docker image using the [DockerDotNet](https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/Docker.DotNet) library:

```
  public Task<Stream> BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync(Stream contents, BuildImageFromDockerfileParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
        if (contents == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contents");
        }

        if (parameters == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters");
        }

        BinaryRequestContent data = new BinaryRequestContent(contents, "application/tar");
        const string path = "build";
        IQueryString queryParameters = new QueryString<BuildImageFromDockerfileParameters>(parameters);
        return this.Client.MakeRequestForStreamAsync(this.Client.NoErrorHandlers, HttpMethod.Post, path, queryParameters, data, cancellationToken);
    }
```

However, I am getting a 500 return from the server, with no error message. The Docker api docs state that:

**The input stream must be a tar archive compressed with one of the following algorithms: identity (no compression), gzip, bzip2, xz.**

I have copied my code below, I would be really grateful if anyone could point out any obvious mistakes. The tar archive is a single folder containing a Dockerfile, created with 7zip.

```
       var parameters = new BuildImageFromDockerfileParameters
        {
            RepositoryTagName = "test-image",
            RemoveIntermediateContainers = true
        };

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\Dockerfile.tar.gz",FileMode.Open))
        {
            await client.Miscellaneous.BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync(fileStream, parameters, new CancellationToken());
        }
```

Dockerfile:

```
#using ubuntu as having trouble with ssl on debian
FROM ubuntu:14.04

#install php
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli

#copy crontab, php script and data files container
COPY my-crontab /
COPY getData.php /
COPY saveddata.xml /

#run crontab
RUN crontab /my-crontab
ENTRYPOINT cron -f
```

Comment: I have managed to create an image by adding files one by one to a tar archive, rather than archiving an entire directory at once. However, the resultant image is just the base Ubuntu image, rather than what is specified in the Dockerfile. I have copied my Dockerfile in the question.

Comment: Please see this question for how I solved this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023184/only-first-line-being-read-in-dockerfile