# Only first line being read in Dockerfile

Tags: c#, unix, docker

I am trying to build an image on a remote linux vm using Docker.DotNet (a c# wrapper for the Docker Rest Api), but only the first line of my Dockerfile is being read:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-cli
```

Consequently, only the base Ubuntu image has been created, and php has not been installed. I have converted the file endings in my Dockerfile to \n (Unix) rather than \r\n (Windows), but this has had no effect. The image repository name is also not being set, as per my api call.

Strangely, if I only include one line in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

Then the image repository name is set, so it looks like something in the second line is causing the problem.

This is the method that calls BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync in Docker.DotNet:

```
static async Task BuildImageFromDockerfile(DockerClient client)
    {
        var parameters = new BuildImageFromDockerfileParameters
        {
            RepositoryTagName = "test-image-python",
            RemoveIntermediateContainers = false
        };

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\DockerProjects\helloworld-py.tar", FileMode.Open))
        {
            await client.Miscellaneous.BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync(fileStream, parameters, new CancellationToken());
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: On examing the logs at /var/log/upstart/docker.log, I am getting this error message: Client disconnected, cancelling job: build

Comment: The connection being closed was the problem, and so this looks to be a problem with Docker.DotNet. Hopefully I'll get chance to create a pull request and fix this in the coming weeks, as apart from BuildFromDockerfile I've found the library very useful. For the time being, I'm just making the api call myself in c#.

Answer (score 1):

The connection being closed was the problem, and so this looks to be a problem with Docker.DotNet. Hopefully I'll get chance to create a pull request and fix this in the coming weeks, as apart from BuildFromDockerfile I've found the library very useful. For the time being, I'm just making the api call myself in c#. – Dan O'Leary